# Have any MySQL query to Update/replace Group By table points into other MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update, mysqlupgrade

I Filter the My (TableA - fields **app_id, user_id, points, tr_type, description**) using Below Query

```
select app_id, user_id,sum(case when tr_type = 'add' then points when tr_type = 'sub' then - points end) as points
from TableA
group by app_id, user_id;
```

In Resuts:

```
app_id  user_id  points
1          1a      10
1          1b      12
1          1c      3
```

Now I have another table (TableB)

```
app_id   user_id   points  desc
1          1a      0       text
1          1b      0       tet
1          1c      0       txt
```

now I need fast replacement query to update TableB point values which is groupby from TableA

Comment: If you can query a number it is far better to do so rather than keep totals in a table as they will almost always be wrong. someone somewhere will do a quick db fix and forget to maintain the totals

Answer (score 0):

You can use a inner join with subqiery for group by  values

```
update tableB b
INNER JOIN (
    select app_id
        , user_id
        ,sum(case when tr_type = 'add' then points when tr_type = 'sub' then - points end) as points
    from TableA
    group by app_id, user_id

) t ON t.app_id = b.app_id
    AND t.user_id = b.user_id 
set b.points = t.points
```